# firebase local server stopped updatig. for an hour now, on each port it have stucked on once served version, on each port it's different one

Tags: firebase, localserver

As in the title.
I was writing my code and checking the results. Everything was workng fine, at some point browser output has stopped updating to latest version of my app. I closed the terminal, opened it again, served my app (on default port 5000) and it has showed the old version. I oppened another terminal served my site on another port(5005) and it worked, site was up to date on 5005, while not updated on the port 5000. Then I made changes and both ports have stuck on their versions. I closed both - the browser and the VScode and opened them again and nothing. I use windows 7 if it metters.

Any clues what might go wrong?

Comment: Did you actually stop the emulator? I have to press ctrl+c to stop the emulator when it becomes unresponsive.  then I run firebase emulators:start and it works again for a while.

Comment: thx for advice, it helped, does not always work thou.